# CentOS 5.8 update from CentOS 5.7

Tags: centos, yum, update

'yum list updates' doesn't show centos-release for 5.8 on some CentOS 5.7 machine.
What does this happen?

machine A

```
[dnd@one:~]$ yum list updates | grep centos-release
[dnd@one:~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 5.7 (Final)
```

machine B

```
[root@l-e0 ~]# yum list updates | grep centos-release 
centos-release.x86_64                 10:5-8.el5.centos                 base    
centos-release-notes.x86_64           5.8-0                             base  
[root@l-e0 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 5.7 (Final)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5.8 has only just been released.  I quote from the CentOS mailing list:

> ```
> Date: Mon, 05 Mar 2012 04:12:01 -0600
> From: Johnny Hughes <johnny@centos.org>
> To: centos@centos.org
> Subject: Re: [CentOS] CentOS 5.8 Critical Samba Update
>
> [...]
> I am populating the CentOS mirrors with the 5.8 release at this time.
>
> We are very close to releasing 5.8, just doing some extended testing,
> which I fully expect it to pass based on the fixes rolled in.
>
> I expect that CentOS-5.8 will be released to the external mirrors in
> less than 24 hours and released to the 24-48 hours after that.
> [...]
> So, look for 5.8 to be released in the next 24-72 hours.
> ```

Depending on how frequently and at what time of day your currently-preferred mirror resyncs, there can be a delay while the new binaries propagate around the whole mirror network; the mirrors that happened to resync at the right time will have them, while those that are waiting for their next resync won't.

If this annoys you, I have found that a `yum clean all` will often allow me to randomly pick a different mirror, and that may have the updates ready to go.

If it **really** annoys you, you should look through the mirrors listed in [the CentOS mirror list](http://www.centos.org/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=30), find one that's close to you and that has the updates, and hardwire it into your `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`.

Or you could just wait another day or two!

Comment: Minsuk: glad to hear it.  Just in case you don't know, local etiquette is that when you're satisfied with an answer, you accept it by clicking in the "tick" outline you see next to that answer.  That drives the SF reputation system for both of us.  My apologies if you already know this.

Comment: +1 for `yum clean all`. `yum update` failed before I ran it, and it's upgrading now afterward because it picked different mirrors.

Comment: MadHatter: Thanks. I didn't know that. Am I right to click the 'v' sign?

Comment: Warren: I did `yum clean all`. but it didn't work at that time. I guess yum still chose same mirror site.. Thanks.